# How do you define uuid indexes in contract tables?

Tags: multi-index, eosio.cdt

I would get table entries by uuid. how can I convert string format `16cadf15-dda7-4be2-8026-c3c7875322d0` to an indexable eosio type ( uint64_t, uint128_t, uint256_t, double or long double).

Or even use as primary key if possible.

```
ACTION saveuuid(string uuid){
  my_table mytable(_self, _self.value);
  mytable.emplace(_self, [&]( auto& row ) {
    row.id = mytable.available_primary_key();
    row.uuid = uuid;
  });
}

TABLE mytable {
      int id;
      string uuid;
      uint128_t primary_key() const { return id; }
      uint128_t by_uuid() const { return uuid.value; } // cast here?

      EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( approvals, (id)(uuid));
    };

    typedef eosio::multi_index<"mytable"_n, mytable,
       eosio::indexed_by<"mytable"_n, eosio::const_mem_fun<poll, string, &poll::by_uuid>>
    > my_table;
```

---

```
TABLE mytable {
      int id;
      string uuid;
      uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
      uint128_t by_uuid() const { return uuid.value; }

      EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( approvals, (id)(uuid));
    };

    typedef eosio::multi_index<"mytable"_n, mytable,
       eosio::indexed_by<"mytable"_n, eosio::const_mem_fun<poll, string, &poll::by_uuid>>
    > my_table;

ACTION saveuuid(string uuid){
  my_table mytable(_self, _self.value);
  mytable.emplace(_self, [&]( auto& row ) {
    row.id = mytable.available_primary_key();
    row.uuid = uuid;  // how to cast ?
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the uuid to a uint128_t and also store it as uint128_t to make it indexable so that you can use it as key.

You can find more info about uuids and how they can be converted [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

The following should work

```
string uuid = "16cadf15-dda7-4be2-8026-c3c7875322d";
std::replace( uuid.begin(), uuid.end(), '-', ''); // remove all '-'
uuid = "Ox"+uuid; // add "0x" hex-prefix to string
uint128_t indexable_uuid = std::strtoul(uuid, 0, 16);. // convert hex-string to uint128_t
```