# Use UUID as primary key in multi_index

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, primarykey, index

How can I use a uuid as the primary.

```
struct [[eosio::table]] blackboxdata {
    name           user;
    std::string    uuid;
    std::string    hash;
    std::string    sqlrequest;
    uint64_t       primary_key() const { return uuid;}
  };
```

> error : no viable conversion from returned value of type 'const std::string'
>         (aka 'const basic_string, allocator >') to function return type 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long')
>                   uint64_t primary_key() const { return uuid;}

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a string as index.
The documentation says:

> They are multi index tables because they support using multiple indexes on the data, the primary index type must be uint64_t and must be unique, but the other, secondary, indexes can have duplicates. You can have up to 16 additional indexes and the field types can be uint64_t, uint128_t, uint256_t, double or long double

So you probably have to do something like this:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] blackboxdata {
    name         user;
    uint64_t     id;
    uint128_t    uuid;
    std::string  hash;
    std::string  sqlrequest;
    uint64_t     primary_key() const { return id;}
    uint128_t    secondary_key() const { return uuid;}
};
```

take a look here on how to convert a [uuid to a uint128_t](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/4339/how-do-you-define-uuid-indexes-in-contract-tables).

If each user is unique,you could use it instead of the additonal uint64_t as primary index.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer,

1- I followed your instruction above but I have 2 errors I put them in comment

2- I have a "hashcompare" action but I don't know how I can compare the hash coming from the data base with the hash stored in the blockchain using uuid with this action.

This my full code

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract("blackbox")]] blackbox : public eosio::contract {
  public:
      blackbox(name receiver, name code,  datastream<const char*> ds): contract(receiver, code, ds) {}

    [[eosio::action]]
    void add(const name user, uint64_t id, std::string uuid,  std::string hash, std::string sqlrequest, std::string date){
        require_auth( user );

        blackboxdata_index addresses( get_self(), get_first_receiver().value );

      std::replace( uuid.begin(), uuid.end(),'-',''); //15:50 error: expected expression
      uuid = "Ox"+uuid; 
      uint128_t indexable_uuid = std::strtoul(uuid, 0, 16); //17:47: error: no viable conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char,char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'const char *'

        addresses.emplace(user, [&]( auto& row ) {
            row.user = user;
        row.id = id;
            row.uuid = indexable_uuid;
            row.hash = hash;
            row.sqlrequest =sqlrequest;
            row.date = date;
        });
    } 

    [[eosio::action]]
    void hashcompare (name user, std::string uuid_database, std::string hash_database){
       require_auth (user)
       blackboxdata_index addresses( get_self(), get_first_receiver().value );

       //how I can compare the hash coming from the data base with the hash stored in the blockchain using uuid with this action.
    }


  private: 
    struct [[eosio::table]] blackboxdata {
    name         user;
    uint64_t     id;
    uint128_t    uuid;
    std::string  hash;
    std::string  sqlrequest;
    std::string  date;
    uint64_t     primary_key() const { return id;}
    uint128_t    secondary_key() const { return uuid;}
};
  typedef eosio::multi_index<"data"_n, blackboxdata,
  indexed_by<"hash"_n, const_mem_fun<blackboxdata, uint128_t, &blackboxdata::secondary_key> > >blackboxdata_index;

};
```